# Register custom constraints

Tags: grails, grails3.2.0

I'm trying to upgrade Grails 2.3.7 project to Grails 3.2.3. In 2.3.7, I used custom constraints and register them in /conf/Config.groovy using:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty.registerNewConstraint('description', my.validation.DescriptionConstraint)
```

Then I can use something like this in domain:

```
static constraints = {
  approvedDate(description: '>= applyDate')
}
```

However, in Grails 3.2.3, When I put above command (and remove org.codehaus.groovy from package name) in /conf/application.groovy I got following error:

```
Error occurred running Grails CLI: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.registerNewConstraint() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.ConfigObject, groovy.util.ConfigObject) values: [[:], [DESCRIPTION_CONSTRAINT:[:]]]
```

I've notice that validation class is somewhat changed in Grails 3. However using constraint class from Grails-validation still got the same error.

All validation plugins I found were long abandoned before Grails 3. And I can't find any document for register new constraint in Grails 3.2.

Comment: Try this:
`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty.registerNewConstraint('description', my.validation.DescriptionConstraint.class)`
[DOC](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.x/api/grails/validation/ConstrainedProperty.html#registerNewConstraint)

Comment: @zfChaos Thanks. However that still got same error. Moreover, `import grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty` got `unable to resolve class grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty` It looks like this file does not in Grails environment yet. I'm trying to register it in `/grails-app/init/Application.groovy` instead. It does not error there. However, I'm porting other part of project so I can't test if it works yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `ConstrainedProperty.registerNewConstraint` in /grails-app/init/BootStrap.groovy works. (tested with Grails 3.2.4)

```
class BootStrap {
  def init = { servletContext ->
    grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty.registerNewConstraint('description', my.validation.DescriptionConstraint)
    // The rest of bootstrap code
  }
}
```

Note. Previously, I call it from `main()` in /grails-app/init/Application.groovy. It works for running application. However, it does not work with integration test.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can create the `runtime.groovy` under `config` and register your constraints in the `runtime.groovy` as in grails 2.x.x:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty.registerNewConstraint('description', my.validation.DescriptionConstraint)
```