# Grails 3.3.1 - Register new constraint

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In previous versions of Grails, I could call:

```
grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty.registerNewConstraint(
                constraintName,
                constraintClass)
```

But now `grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty` is deprecated, and the class to use instead, `grails.gorm.validation.ConstrainedProperty`, does not have the method `registerNewConstraint`.

How can I register a new constraint in Grails 3.3.1?

Comment: Any use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071987/register-custom-constraints

Comment: Unfortunately that suggestion does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since grails 3.3.x you can't register constraints with the `ConstraintedProperty` the package doesn't matter. You should use the [ConstraintRegistry](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/api/org/grails/datastore/gorm/validation/constraints/registry/ConstraintRegistry.html). See the part `Grails Validator and ConstrainedProperty API Deprecated` of [grails documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#applyingConstraints)