# How to register a custom constraint

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0, grails3

I've created a custom constraint (most code copied from [`NullableConstraint`](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-validation/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/validation/constraints/NullableConstraint.java)) that I'd like to use in my project.

How do I register this new constraint so I can use it in my domain classes and command objects? I've tried following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071987/register-custom-constraints) but that didn't work. I also tried copying the code from [here](https://github.com/rmorrise/grails-cascade-validation/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/cascade/validation/CascadeValidationGrailsPlugin.groovy) but that didn't work either.

Comment: Grails validation (and other things) were refactored out to GORM after Grails 3.3, a disruptive change that left several important aspects scantily documented.

Answer (score 1):

I set up a few custom Constraint classes in a Grails 3 project and carried them forward to Grails 4.

In my Application class, I register the custom constraints to 2 constraint registries.  There are a few methods on the Application class you can choose from to implement this.  I don't know if my selection was the best.

```
void doWithDynamicMethods(){
    //for domains
    applicationContext.getBean(
        org.grails.datastore.mapping.validation.ValidatorRegistry
    ).addConstraintFactory( someConstraintFactory )
    
    //for command objects
    (
        (DefaultConstraintEvaluator)
        applicationContext.getBean(
            org.grails.datastore.gorm.validation.constraints.eval.ConstraintsEvaluator
        )
    ).constraintRegistry.addConstraintFactory( someConstraintFactory )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Config.groovy add the follow:

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    validMobilePhone(validator: { value, obj, errors ->
        if (!value) return

        value = PhoneNumberUtils.sanitizeNumber(value)

        if (!PhoneNumberUtils.validateMobilePhone(value)) {
            errors.rejectValue('mobilePhone', "invalid")
        }
    })

    nonNegative(min: new BigDecimal(0))

}
```

And then use this constraint in your domain:

```
static constraints = {
    value shared: 'nonNegative'
}
```

Comment: Grails 4.0.5 docs says to include this in grails-app/conf/runtime.groovy. If the closure takes 3 args it must work directly on the errors object. This means the property name gets hardwired -- not suitable for a shared validator. Have the closure take 1 or 2 args and return a list or string according to validator doco. All this is a useful workaround, but does not answer the original question.